# How do I know which fields are indexed in pouchdb if I use query() API?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am new to `pouchdb` and I am reading below source code:

```
                    db.query('product_index', {
                        startkey: ["01234"],
                        endkey: ["01234", {}],
                        include_docs: false
                    });
```

this code executes for a long time. After read some `pouchdb` document it looks like it builds index on the database when it run the first time. But I don't understand which fields are indexed based on above code.

Below code I can see it builds index on field `foo`. But how can I understand `query` API for building index? What is the different between using `query` and `createIndex` from index perceptive?

```
db.createIndex({
  index: {
    fields: ['foo']
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [PouchDB Guide](https://pouchdb.com/guides/) [Bulk operations](https://pouchdb.com/guides/bulk-operations.html) section [Please use 'allDocs()'. Seriously.](https://pouchdb.com/guides/bulk-operations.html#please-use-alldocs)?

> Far too many developers overlook this valuable API, because they
>   misunderstand it. When a developer says "my PouchDB app is slow!", it
>   is usually because they are using the slow `query()` API when they
>   should be using the fast `allDocs()` API.

When designing your data structures it's very important to bear that in mind.  You should define your record id fields to optimize data accessibility through `allDocs()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The `query` API is very slow on the first time running it. It is very fast after that. Is there a document say what happens on `query` API? Does it build index into views? Does it require a lot of memory if the database is big?

Comment: Views are reindexed at query time. So yeah, the first query might be slow but the others should be faster.